# cant get value of key prop in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary

```
   const arry = [{id: 1, key: "fsdfsdfs6645",sub: "AB"},
                 { id: 2,key: "jhkhkhjk55",sub: "BC"},
                 {id: 3,key: "iksstrrtrk55",sub: "VK"}
                 ];
```

> that arry i am using here

```
import { arry } from "./constant";

export default function App() {
  const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.key);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select onChange={onChangeHandler}>
        {arry.map((obj) => {
          return <option key={obj.key}>{obj.sub}</option>;
        })}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> I was trying to access key value through onChange
> How can i access that key value?

Here is Code Link [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-newton-p78gi?file=/src/App.js:23-375)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `value` attribute of `<option>`:

```js
export default function App() {
  function onChangeHandler(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);  // value
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={onChangeHandler}>
        {arry.map(obj => (
          <option key={obj.key} value={obj.key}>{obj.sub}</option>)
        )}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: what if i want to get multiple attribute value?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can stringify the `obj` before passing it to `value`: `value={JSON.stringify(obj)}`. And then parse it within the handler. If you meant how to select multiple values within one `<select>`, check this out: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp